# How often does Event.RENDER get called?

Tags: actionscript-3, events

If I added some objects to the Display List via addChild(), how often does Event.RENDER get fired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called only if you explicitly use stage.invalidate();

You should note that there are certain bugs and special considerations (or at least there were bugs in FP9, which is the last time I actively used stage.invalidate) related to listeners for Event.RENDER.

1. Regardless of how many different objects listen for Event.RENDER events, if even one of them calls removeEventListener(Event.RENDER... then **all** listeners are removed.  To my knowledge, RENDER is the only event on which this bug occurs (or used to in FP9)
2. You cannot use stage.invalidate() **inside of an Event.RENDER handler**.  Since you'd only call stage.invalidate in order to trigger the render handler, this should hopefully not be a problem.

EDIT:  bigp in the comment below makes a valid observation that Flex may indeed use stage.invalidate under the hood.  Take my answer as one that is applicable strictly to vanilla AS3 without any accompanying framework such as Flex.

Comment: Does it get called every frame then if you use stage.invalidate()?

Comment: It is **only** called when you explicitly call stage.invalidate().  If you call stage.invalidate inside of an ENTER_FRAME handler, then yes.  Otherwise, no.  You generally *won't* call it inside an ENTER_FRAME handler.  It was intended to be a way to make "last minute" updates to the display list before it renders.  Unfortunately it's not always even successful at that.  If you are targeting FP10 you might do better to make use of the other frame events such as FRAME_CONSTRUCTED, or EXIT_FRAME to have better control over precisely when things happen.  What exactly do you need .RENDER for?

Comment: I think this is a partial correct answer. In Flex applications this can get triggered via any components changing in appearance (rollovers, transitions, effects, tweens). It might internally call the 'stage.invalidate();' method but I thought it might be worth noting that under-the-hood, Flex handles it quite everywhere a visual element may change.

Comment: @bigp Thanks bigp, you can tell I seldom work with Flex, but rather with plain AS3.